# Посчитать количество итераций цикла do while

Tags: c#, while, roslyn

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посчитать количество итераций цикла do while с помощью Roslyn? Нужен семантический анализатор, который бы определял итерации.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace testAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var code = @"
    public void FindI()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int a = 17;
        do 
        {
            a+=9;
            i++;
        }
        while (a<104);
    }";
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
            var doStatement = syntaxTree
                .GetRoot()
                .DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<DoStatementSyntax>()
                .First();
            //??????????
            Console.WriteLine("num of iterations: " );
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а переменнная `i` у вас разве не итерации считает?

Comment: да, она для итераций

Comment: если после `while` вывести `i-1`, то это и будет число сделанных итераций

Comment: Вы хотите не выполняя кода оценить количество итераций произвольного цикла? Это сделать [нельзя](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Если есть какие-либо ограничения, которые позволят это сделать (например, цикл всегда имеет один и тот же вид), то укажите их в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

проверить код можете [здесь](https://rextester.com/LIN69415)

`i-1` - кол-во итераций

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int test = 0;
            do
            {
                test+=20;
                i++;
                if(test > 1000) break;

            }
            while(true);
            Console.Write((i-1).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно, чтобы синтаксический анализатор это делал)